# PHP script only allow traffic from a certain domain?

Tags: php

Is there a simple script that would only allow visitors if they originate from a website of my choice?

Comment: @Brian There's absolutely nothing wrong with asking this question on Stack Overflow. (It is a pretty lazy question that said.)

Comment: @middaparka I agree, however this question has considerable coverage from other sources on the web, so I didn't see a point in consuming more resources here. Hence, my suggestion.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: Please stop telling people to google. This site IS one of the top google results, just link to a page if you know of it otherwise that isn't helpful. *(Assuming "favorite search engine" is google)

Comment: @Brian Driscoll - agree with others.  There are few questions on this site that could NOT be answered with a well-crafted Google search.  It takes as long to answer the question as it does to be obtuse about it.  At the end of the day: why be stingy with basic knowledge?

Comment: @Chris - Happy that you agree. I am not one to repeat the work that others have so painstakingly done, so I don't strive to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Checking the referrer is the most reliable way to accomplish this, but you should be aware that not all user agents (aka browsers) send a complete or correct referrer.

Something like this:

```
$target_site = 'http://www.google.com';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match("/$target_site/",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  // do something with people from google.com
} else {
  // do something else with everyone else
}
```

Read more about it: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/

PHP manual on `$_SERVER` superglobal: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: To add to your first point, I've had Chrome return `favicon.ico` as the referer quite a bit for some reason.

Comment: how would i modify that code to redirect good users to my website and the disallowed users to an error page?

Comment: Using the php command `header`.  Example: `header('location:http://www.gotothissite.com');`.  See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$_SERVER['http_referer']` but that can be easily faked.

Answer (score 0):

If you get their referrer information you could check it against a list of accepted website origins and redirect them back to the site they came from if you don't want them.

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```